# How do I move the text in a silverlight textbox

Tags: silverlight, textbox

I make a silverlight TextBox.  The Text is vertically centered in the box so that I am required to make the textbox a certain size in order to see the text.

Can I make the text appear at the top of the box so that I am not required to have such large textboxes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to put the text at the top of the textbox then instead of VerticalAlignment="Center" use VerticalAlignment="Top"

If you feel that the text is not filling the textbox then try using a negative number for the padding property in your xaml e.g. Padding="-3"